# does textview in fragment needs to be declared static

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have started to learn android recently and i was looking at a fragment example in a video tutorial 
in the tutorial they haven't made the textview static but when i tried to implement fragment with some changes in the code i started to get null pointer exception my code looks like this

```
public class BlankFragment2 extends Fragment {

TextView tv;

public BlankFragment2() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank_fragment2, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    tv= (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txt2);
}



public void setName(String name){
    //tv=(TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txt2);
    if(tv == null){
        System.out.println("tv is null");
    }
    tv.setText("Hi "+name);
}
}
```

i am getting null pointer exception at settext unless i make the textview static can someone please explain why

this is not duplicate of what is NPE i know what NPE is and why it shows up my question here is that after initializing the textview in onActivityCreated why it is null again in setname function

Comment: NO . In which layout `R.id.txt2` exists ?

Comment: in fragment_blank_fragment2

Comment: @ADM this is definitely not a duplicate of what is NPE i know why NPE comes, i have updated the question to explain the problem in better way

Comment: This does not make any difference Ultimately you are accessing a Null object which will gives you NPE. The root cause is `getActivity()` points to parent `Activity` and your view is part of fragment not activity.

Comment: @ADM i also tried View view = getView();  then view.findViewById(R.id.txt2) still getting NPE

Comment: Just use the solution right below. Read [Creating a Fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating).

Answer (score 1):

> NullPointerException is thrown when an application attempts to use an
>   object reference that has the null value.

**FYI**

- You should return **VIEW's** object
- Check **`findViewById(R.id.txt2`** . Make sure you this **ID** present in **XML**.

**Don't**

```
tv= (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txt2);
```

**Do**

```
 tv= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt2);
```

Try this way

```
     @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank_fragment2, container, false);
             tv= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt2);
            return view;
        }
```

Comment: i tried, this also gives NPE

Comment: What's wrong with [getActivity().findViewById()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int)) ?

Comment: @pawndoe check `findViewById(R.id.txt2);` . Id tx2 is valid or not?

Comment: @pawndoe After change `Clean-Rebuild and run`

Comment: did that still getting NPE

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya id txt2 is valid since making textview static solves NPE. problem is that after initializing textview in onActivityCreated it is again null in setname method

Comment: @pawndoe oh...sloppy mistake

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya can you explain why it is null again in setname

Comment: @pawndoe I assume `String name` is null. Debug please.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya i tried to sysout name, it is not null instead the if(tv==null) in showname method returns true

Comment: @pawndoe you should check `if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name))`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya i suppose that would check if the name is empty or not but the problem here is that textview tv is null in setname method so calling settext on tv return NPE so i wanted to know why tv is null after i have initialized it in onActivityCreated method

Answer (score 1):

Not `getActivity().findViewById()`, it must be `view.findViewById()` because `Activity.findViewById()` will look for a `View` in the `Activity` layout, whereas  `view.findViewById()` will look for the `View` in the `Fragment` layout.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank_fragment2, container, false);
    return inflatedView;
}
```

And in `onViewCreated` you can initialise your `TextView`

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    // here goes your intialisation using view
    tv= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt2);
}
```

Make sure you have a `TextView` with the id `txt2` in `fragment_blank_fragment2.xml`

Comment: What's wrong with [getActivity().findViewById()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int)) ?

Comment: ` getActivity().findViewById() ` will search for the id in activity layout. will give NPE

Comment: this is also giving NPE

Comment: Make sure that `R.id.txt2` exists in `R.layout.fragment_blank_fragment2`

Comment: You should put that in your answer is what I mean... Hopefully you'll like my edit ;) Good answer though !

Comment: since making the textview static solves the problem means that txt2 is present and accessible

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys it was a stupid mistake on my side, 
in my mainactivity i wrote

```
BlankFragment2 frag2 = new BlankFragment2();
    frag2.setName(name);
```

i corrected it by writing

```
BlankFragment2 frag2=(BlankFragment2)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag2);
    fragb.setName(name);
```

now it is working

Comment: Glad to see you fixed that.